# How to determine which of multiple selectors was chosen?

Tags: jquery

If I specify several different selectors to have the same result, is there any way I can obtain the string of the selector that was chosen?

```
$('#one, #two, #three').on( "click", function(){
    console.log(???);
    //#one
});
```

For example if someone clicks on the element `#one` how do I print `#one` to the console?

Answer (score 5):

Try to use the `this` reference inside the click event,

```
$('#one, #two, #three').on( "click", function(){
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xj35c/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this: You will get current `Event` value in `this` object.

```
$('#one, #two, #three').on( "click", function(Event){
    console.log("#" + this.id);
    //OR
    console.log("#" + Event.target.id);
    //#one
});
```